# sending html input values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send a message, which has values entered in an input box.
For example, "Hey, my name is firstname" (`fname`: the input value) and "lastname" (`lname`: the input value).

How can I include entered values from the input box in the message body?

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    
  <head> 
    <title>Sending Mail</title> 
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function sendEmail() { 
        Email.send({ 
            Host: "smtp.gmail.com", 
            Username: "", 
            Password: "", 
            To: '', 
            From: "", 
            Subject: "", 
            Body: "",  // send entered values from input box
        }) 
            .then(function (message) { 
            alert("Mail has been sent successfully") 
            }); 
        } 
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
    <form method="post"> 
     <input type="text"  name="fname">  
         <input type="text"  name="lname">
        <input type="button" value="Send Mail"
            onclick="sendEmail()" /> 
    </form> 
  </body> 
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `template literals` like the example below or you can concatenate them with the `+` symbol like I do in `emailBody` variable below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

  <head> 
    <title>Sending Mail</title> 

    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function sendEmail() {
        var firstName = document.querySelector('input[name="fname"]').value;
        var lastName = document.querySelector('input[name="lname"]').value;
        
        var emailBody = 'Welcome ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName;
        
        Email.send({ 
          Host: "smtp.gmail.com", 
          Username: "", 
          Password: "", 
          To: '', 
          From: "", 
          Subject: "", 
          Body: `Welcome ${firstName} ${lastName}`,  // send entered values from input box
        }).then(function (message) { 
          alert("Mail has been sent successfully") 
        }); 
      } 
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
    <form method="post"> 
      <input type="text"  name="fname">  
      <input type="text"  name="lname">
      <input type="button" value="Send Mail" onclick="sendEmail()" /> 
    </form> 
  </body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to query the DOM to find the value of each form input. One way to do this is with `document.querySelector` which searches the DOM using a CSS-like selector. This query will return the first element it finds using that selector or undefined if it can't find anything.

For input fields, it will return an InputElement which has properties associated with it, such as the current `value`. You can then use these values to compile a custom string which you can pass as the body for your email message.

```
var fname = document.querySelector('input[name=fname]').value;

Email.send({
   ...
   Body: `Hello, ${fname}!`
})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @JohnConde. I figured it was self-explanatory, but I've updated the answer to provide a more clear description of the logic for posterity.

Comment: Self explanatory to some people is rocket surgery to others. :)